# Using Pandas to concatenate/copy Dataframes of equal shape, but dataframe creates offset data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I am making a program that calculates an average voltage from a charge cycle and discharge cycle of a battery. To get this voltage, I find the end of the charge or discharge sequence by setting my "ES_code" to a number that the machine uses to indicate the charge or discharge is done.

I use Pandas to create a dataframe for the average voltage at the charge and another dataframe for the discharge and when I then try to combine the two dataframes, I get this output:

```
            0         1
321  4.028119       NaN
342       NaN  4.090909
532  4.205128       NaN
553       NaN  4.095238
743  4.193133       NaN
```

For the first dataframe I am calling it "ch_chg", I am filtering out all values in the csv file that don't have the ES_Code I am looking for. This creates a dataframe which ends up being 1000 rows by 17 columns. Afterwards, I calculate the voltage using 2 columns Energy and Capacity. I do the same for discharge. What I then try to do is take just the voltages that I calculated from the chg_chg and chg_dis and put it into a new dataframe called vav. When I put them together, that's when I get the NaN values.

I can't find a good way to either get rid of all the NaNs and realign the data, **despite both average voltages being the same size:**

```
(1000, 1)
(1000, 1)
```

Here is where I create the 2 dataframes:

```
ch = pd.read_csv('cycles.csv', header=1)
ch = ch.drop("Rec#", axis=1)

ES_code1 = ch['ES']==132
ch_chg = ch[ES_code1].copy()
ch_chg['Vavg_charge']= ch_chg["Energy (WHr)"] / ch_chg["Capacity (AHr)"]

ES_code2 = ch['ES']==136
ch_dis = ch[ES_code2].copy()
ch_dis['Vavg_discharge']= ch_dis["Energy (WHr)"] / ch_dis["Capacity (AHr)"]
```

And here is where I try to concatenate them:

```
vav_Discharge = ch_dis[['Vavg_discharge']].copy()
vav_Charge = ch_chg[['Vavg_charge']].copy()
vav = pd.concat([vav_Charge,vav_Discharge], ignore_index=True, axis=1)
```

Here's a sample of the header of the csv file I am working with:

```
 Cycle P  Cycle C  Step Test Time (sec) Step Time (sec)  Capacity (AHr)  \
0       0        1     1               0               0             0.0   
1       0        1     1          8.3536          8.3536             0.0   
2       0        1     1          8.3536          8.3536             0.0   
3       0        1     1         59.9978         59.9978             0.0   
4       0        1     2         60.0208           0.023             0.0   

   Energy (WHr)  Current (A)  Voltage (V) MD   ES       DPT  ACImp (Ohms)  \
0           0.0         0.00        4.178  R    0  12:35:07           0.0   
1           0.0         0.00        4.179  S  192  12:35:15           0.0   
2           0.0         0.00        4.175  R  192  13:47:08           0.0   
3           0.0         0.00        4.176  R  129  13:48:00           0.0   
4           0.0         0.47        4.154  D    0  13:48:00           0.0   

   EVTemp (C)   Aux #1  Units  
0           0  39.1112      C  
1           0  39.3307      C  
2           0  44.9742      C  
3           0  44.9588      C  
4           0  44.9588      C
```

In short, I would like to create a single dataframe (vav) without the NaN's being offset.  The NaN values do not show up for the individual voltage dataframes I make (vav_Charge and vav_Discharge), but when I try to put together these values into one dataframe, I get the Nan values. I would like to be able to plot this data but can't figure out a way to do so.

Comment: How are you trying to construct this first data frame?

Comment: Hi sorry for the lack of clarity, the first dataframe I am creating by filtering out all values in the csv file that don't have the ES_Code I am looking for, which ends up being 1000 points. From there, I take all of that data and create ch_chg. Afterwards, I calculate the voltage using 2 columns Energy and Capacity. I do the same for dischare.

What I then try to do is take just the voltages that I calculated from the chg_chg and chg_dis and put it into a new dataframe called vav. When I put them together, that's when I get the NaN values

Comment: You can edit your question, rather commenting, as people might not see this

Comment: @Sershers what code are you using to put it together

Comment: I actually found a solution, I ended up using Numpy to create 2 separate arrays and then concatenating them. Would it be best if I deleted the question since I solved it? I'm sorry, this is my first question.

Answer (score 0):

Add this piece of code after your concat:

```
vav = vav[0].fillna(vav[1])
```

That should merge your two columns into a single one.

Comment: you can also use `vav = vav[0].combine_first(vav[1])` to achive the same thing

Comment: @Sershers are you wanting a single column off all values or do you want two columns with the NaNs removed and all data moved up?

Comment: I wanted to create 2 separate columns, but I found out that I can put the two individual columns into numpy and create 2 separate arrays and then concatenate them to have 2 separate columns

Answer (score 0):

I managed to put the 2 voltage columns without the NaN values by using NumPy by creating 2 separate arrays and concatenating them as so:

```
Arr1 = vav_Charge.to_numpy()
Arr2 = vav_Discharge.to_numpy()
Arr = np.concatenate((Arr1, Arr2), axis=1)
vavg = pd.DataFrame(Arr, columns = ['Vav Charge', 'Vav Discharge'])
```